# confirmation box on Row Command when some condition is true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a confirmation box on GridView Row Command. If certain condition is true.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="chkStatus" 
           Class='<%#Eval("Status")==DBNull.Value ? "":Eval("Status").ToString()!="True" ? "notrec" : "rec" %>'           
                                        runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RowID")+";"+ Eval("Status")%>'  CommandName="change" >
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

If Status is True I want to Show a Confirmation Popup.
Please help If anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it inline like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="chkStatus" 
    OnClientClick='<%# (Eval("Status") != null && Eval("Status").ToString().ToLower()=="true") ? "return confirm(\"Do you want to change?\");":"return true;"  %>'
    runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RowID")+";"+ Eval("Status")%>'     
    CommandName="change" >TEST
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about to add `CssClass` attribute to your LinkButton like:

```
CssClass='<%#Eval("Status")==DBNull.Value ? "":Eval("Status").ToString()!="True" ? "confirmclass" : "" %>'
```

and then use jQuery

```
$(".confirmclass").click(function () {
    return confirm("Really dude?");
});
```